# Multiple projects all using redux on the same page

Tags: redux, react-redux

Let's say for example I am working on a website which makes use of redux. Then I want to import a different project, e.g. some embedded app, which also uses redux.

So then I have a website written using react & redux, with an embedded app, which also uses react & redux, but neither projects *know* that the other project uses redux.

Will this be a problem? Will there be any conflicts? And how would the chrome redux plugin work? Would it be able to pick up both redux stores?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you plan to embed. It should not be problem.
About Chrome Redux plugin, I'm not sure about this. 
you can use IFrame. There should ideally be no problem doing this, till you are on the same domain. 
or
If you choose the Web-component way. It will give you shadow dom inside. This can be used to create a widget which then can be used anywhere without conflicting with parent in anyway.

> see the
>   https://auth0.com/blog/web-components-how-to-craft-your-own-custom-components/

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I say embed, I just mean i'll be importing an external project in the form of a react component & sticking that onto the page somewhere.